# What type of Object does Spinner.getItemAtPosition(...) return?

Tags: android, type-conversion, android-spinner, return-type

What will this statement return?

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Where `parent` is a parent view for a spinner and position is the selected position from the spinner view.

Answer (score 5):

I assume the "parent" you are talking about is a Spinner. In this case:

```
Spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos);
```

**will always return the type of object that you filled the Spinner with**.

**An example using a CustomType:** (the Spinner is filled with Items of type "CustomType", therefore getItemAtPosition(...) will return CustomType)

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
CustomType [] customArray = new CustomType[] { .... your custom items here .... };

// fill an arrayadapter and set it to the spinner
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, customArray);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);  

CustomType type = (CustomType) spinner.getItemAtPosition(0); // it will return your CustomType so you can safely cast to it
```

**Another example using a String Array:** (the Spinner is filled with Items of type "String", therefore getItemAtPosition(...) will return String)

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String[] stringArray= new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };

// fill an arrayadapter and set it to the spinner
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringArray);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);  

String item = (String ) spinner.getItemAtPosition(0); // it will return your String so you can safely cast to it
```

Answer (score 1):

It will return object of `dataType` you are displaying in spinner.

suppose you are displaying String array then it will return String.

if you are displaying Integer array then it will return Integer and so on.