# Using spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos) to control things

Tags: android, spinner

I find an example how can one find the selected item of a spinner when using a String Array here:
[What type of Object does Spinner.getItemAtPosition(...) return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288270/what-type-of-object-does-spinner-getitematposition-return)

But how can I use the found item in my application?

I have in my application this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

  // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
  String item = (String) spinner4.getItemAtPosition(pos); // Which Item was selected?
  //if item = 1 was selected then spinner2 (blokkora) should be visible, and spinner5 should be invisible
  spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // blokkora should be visible
  spinner5.setVisibility(View.GONE); // ora should be invisible
  //if pos = 2 then spinner5 (ora) should be visible, and spinner2 should be invisible
  spinner5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // ora should be visible
  spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE); // blokkora should be invisible

}
```

The code above does not work.

How can I control which spinner (spinner2 or spinner5) be visible and invisible?

My code is now this ( after I added Adithya's code ):

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        String item = (String) spinner4.getItemAtPosition(pos); // Which subject was selected?
        switch (Integer.parseInt(item)) {
            case 1:
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // blokkora should be visible
                spinner5.setVisibility(View.GONE); // ora should be unvisible
                break;
            case 2:
                spinner5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // ora should be visible
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE); // blokkora should be unvisible
                break;
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        spinner5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // ora should be visible
        spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE); // blokkora should be unvisible
    }
}
```

It does not work. Why?

The layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ora_keltezese"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tantargy_neve"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#d9ffd7"
            android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
            android:text="@string/keltezes"
            android:textColor="#067400"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hianyzokra_mutat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oravazlat_mentese"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/hianyzokra_mutat"
            android:textColor="#FF4C8747"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tanitasi_egysegre_mutat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hianyzok"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/tanitasi_egysegre_mutat"
            android:textColor="#FF4C8747"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/oktatasi_celokra_mutat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tanitasi_egyseg"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/oktatasi_celokra_mutat"
            android:textColor="#FF4C8747"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nevelesi_celokra_mutat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oktatasi_celok"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/nevelesi_celokra_mutat"
            android:textColor="#FF4C8747"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/az_oravazlat_szovegere_mutat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nevelesi_celok"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/az_oravazlat_szovegere_mutat"
            android:textColor="#FF4C8747"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a_naplo_szovegere_mutat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kepek_az_orahoz"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/naplo"
            android:textColor="#4c8747"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tanitasi_het_sorszamara_mutat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/csokkenti_blokkorat"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#d9ffd7"
            android:text="@string/tanitasi_het_sorszamara_mutat"
            android:textColor="#067400"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tanitasi_het_sorszama"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tanitasi_het_sorszamara_mutat"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tanitasi_het_sorszamara_mutat"
            android:background="#d9ffd7"
            android:text="@string/tanitasi_het_sorszama"
            android:textColor="#067400"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/a_naplo_szovege"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/a_naplo_szovegere_mutat"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/naplo_az_orarol"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/az_oravazlat_szovege"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/hianyzok"
            android:layout_below="@+id/az_oravazlat_szovegere_mutat"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/az_oravazlat_szovege"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hianyzok"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hianyzokra_mutat"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hianyzok"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nevelesi_celok"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nevelesi_celokra_mutat"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/nevelesi_celok"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/oktatasi_celok"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oktatasi_celokra_mutat"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/oktatasi_celok"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tanitasi_egyseg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tanitasi_egysegre_mutat"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/tanitasi_egyseg"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/tantargy_neve"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/blokkora"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Spinner"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/csokkenti_blokkorat"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ora_keltezese"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/csokkenti_blokkorat" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/ora"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/csokkenti_blokkorat"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ora_keltezese"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/csokkenti_blokkorat" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/osztaly"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tantargy_neve"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/orarend" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/orarend"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tantargy_neve"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ora_keltezese" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/oravazlat_mentese"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tanitasi_het_sorszamara_mutat"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/oravazlat_mentese"
            android:textColor="#308b24"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/oravazlat_betoltese"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/oravazlat_mentese"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/oravazlat_mentese"
            android:text="@string/button"
            android:textColor="#308b24"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tanulok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/oravazlat_mentese"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/oravazlat_mentese"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/oravazlat_betoltese"
            android:text="@string/tanulok"
            android:textColor="#308b24"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/csokkenti_blokkorat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ora_keltezese"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/csokkenti_blokkorat"
            android:textColor="#308b24"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:onClick="decreaseSpinnerItemPosition" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/noveli_blokkorat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tanulok"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/csokkenti_blokkorat"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/csokkenti_blokkorat"
            android:onClick="increaseSpinnerItemPosition"
            android:text="@string/noveli_blokkorat"
            android:textColor="#308b24"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/kepek_az_orahoz"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/az_oravazlat_szovege"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/kepek_az_oravazlathoz">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mygallery"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: In Android Studio there is a message that says: Class 'CustomOnItemSelectedListener is never used'. So, how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you call `setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener())` on the spinner?

Comment: No, I don't, but now I add the line to my code:  `spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());`  Is that right?

Comment: I inserted the above line bellow the `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` but when launch the application, it does crash. Where to insert it?

Comment: insert it after you have found reference to the spinner,i.e after `Spinner spinner4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);`

Comment: I inserted it like this: `spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tantargy_neve);
        spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());` but the app crashes.

Comment: Is CustomOnItemSelectedListener an inner class? if notmake it an inner class ,because you are accessing the spinner views inside it.and also make all 5 spinners global .

Comment: I make all 5 spinner global. I declared them bellow the: `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {` line. I did make CustomOnItemSelectedListener an inner class by removing the public from it's beginning: `class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {` The application still crash. Why?

Comment: what is the logcat showing?

Comment: logcat shows this: `06-28 13:07:13.064 9118-9118/hu.cspl.oravazlataim_001 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: hu.cspl.oravazlataim_001, PID: 9118
                                                                        Theme: themes:{}
                                                                        java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Válassz ki egy tantárgyat!"
                                                                            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)`

Comment: Which line gives that error?

Comment: The line which gives that error is: `switch (Integer.parseInt(item)) {` Maybe should be String instead of Integer in that line?

Comment: I have updated the answer to `switch(pos)`. try it.

Comment: @Aditya It works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a switch on the position,

```
switch(pos){
            case 1:
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinner5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case 2:
                spinner5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }
```

In layout file add
`android:visibility="visible"`
to spinner4,spinner2 and 
`android:visibility="gone"`
to other spinners.

Comment: I tried this but it has no effect in my application. The spinner2 and spinner5 is one above the other in the layout out there. So what am I missing here?

Comment: in your xml set `android:visibility="gone"` for all but first one.

Comment: Do you mean: to set android:visibility="gone" for spinner5 but not for spinner2? Because one of these two perfectly covers the other in the layout. I do not know now which one is above and which one is bellow to the other. However, I tried to set for spinner5 this: android:visibility="gone" and build my app again, but this does not help. Why?

Comment: Post the layout file.

Comment: I just posted the layout file.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using

        //get your spinner id
        int viewId = view.getId();
        String item = null;
        if(viewId == R.id.SPINNER4){
            item = (String) spinner4.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        }else if(viewId == R.id.SPINNER5){
            item = (String) spinner5.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is very simple but use first thing , like position or string any item select and get item for spinner .

Comment: spinner .setOnitemSelectListner(new ItemSelected Listner)

Comment: String str= parent.getItemAtPosition(position);